# naive Bayes error : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, naivebayes

i am trying to make a prediction model with naive bays classifier by following data set structure

```
> str(train_set)
'data.frame':   1442 obs. of  19 variables:
 $ Age                   : num  59 58 56 55 53 52 52 55 51 53 ...
 $ Dependents            : num  2 1 2 2 1 1 0 2 2 0 ...
 $ NumCompaniesWorked    : num  1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 ...
 $ SalaryRise...         : num  12 13 14 21 11 14 18 15 11 16 ...
 $ WeekHours             : num  40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 ...
 $ TenureWorking         : num  48 46 44 43 41 41 40 41 40 41 ...
 $ NumberProjectsLastYear: num  3 1 2 3 3 5 2 3 2 4 ...
 $ TenureCompany         : num  44 41 40 40 37 36 36 36 36 36 ...
 $ TenureRole            : num  10 10 10 6 6 18 7 9 9 7 ...
 $ LastPromotion         : num  15 1 4 2 1 11 15 15 0 1 ...
 $ TenureManager         : num  6 8 13 13 16 9 12 0 10 9 ...
 $ MonthlyIncome         : num  1650 2220 3047 3134 2697 ...
 $ DistanceHomeOffice    : int  32 14 1 36 4 1 3 11 7 3 ...
 $ JobDedication         : int  3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 3 2 ...
 $ JobPerformance        : int  3 3 3 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ FacilitiesSatisfaction: int  4 4 4 3 3 3 1 4 3 3 ...
 $ RoleSatisfaction      : int  4 3 1 4 1 3 3 2 2 4 ...
 $ HierarchySatisfaction : int  4 3 3 3 1 1 4 4 2 2 ...
 $ Churn                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
```

so i used "klaR" library to make the model

```
library(klaR)
model <- NaiveBayes(Churn ~ ., data = train_set)
```

but the R issue out of bounds error, i don't know how should i define the bounds.

```
Error in `[.default`(x, , 2) : subscript out of bounds
```

also i found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361103/error-in-predict-naivebayes-subscript-out-of-bounds) that raise similar problem but it doesn't have response. 
please help me with a solution or a proper link

Comment: Can you add a subset of your data (e.g. using `dput`) so that we can reproduce your issue on our machines? Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for respond, do you want me to add the data set or part of data set?